# macOS Mojave cannot upsize disk APFS

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mojave, disk-utility, partition

I am trying to resize my disk (make it bigger in size), but I do not know how. I search a lot of tutorials and read a lot of forums but nothing seems to work.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *268.4 MB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     101.4 MB   disk0s1
   2:           Linux Filesystem                         163.9 MB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.1 GB     disk1
   1:                  Apple_HFS macOS Base System       2.0 GB     disk1s1

/dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *137.4 GB   disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         68.5 GB    disk2s2

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +68.5 GB    disk3
                                 Physical Store disk2s2
   1:                APFS Volume Mojave                  57.1 GB    disk3s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 45.3 MB    disk3s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                522.9 MB   disk3s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      20.5 KB    disk3s4
```

When I try to resize it with

```
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer /dev/disk2s2 0
```

I get this error

```
Started APFS operation
Error: -69743: The new size must be different than the existing size
```

Any solutions for resizing this disk? It is a virtual disk in a VM on unRAID.

Comment: Did you resize the virtual disk disk2 (after setting a size of 64 GiB initially)?

Comment: @Daan, I missed the part of your question where you state this is a VM. My answer would not have helped solve your problem.

Comment: Yes I did, I gave the drive a 128G capacity

Comment: Does anyone have a solution??